# Upgrade spring from 3.2 to 4.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Pre-upgrade steps:

1) updated all xml namespace locations to not include version information as recommended by (http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/28/do-not-specify-version-numbers-in-spring-schema-references/)

2) updated parent pom.xml to 4.0.0.RELEASE

Everything compiles but while deploying the upgraded war I receive this exception:

> 19:22:25,480 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 108) Context initialization failed:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   org.springframework.core.DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer does not
>   implement the requested interface
>   org.springframework.core.ParameterNameDiscoverer  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
>
> 19:22:25,480 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 108) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./mpd-builder:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./mpd-builder:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   org.springframework.core.DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer does not
>   implement the requested interface
>   org.springframework.core.ParameterNameDiscoverer  at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   org.springframework.core.DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer does not
>   implement the requested interface
>   org.springframework.core.ParameterNameDiscoverer  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>     ... 6 more

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a version conflict in my child pom.xml. It was pointing to spring 3.2 and the parent was pointing to 4.0.0